# Send Click Message to another application process

Tags: c#, .net, winapi

I have a scenario, i need to send click events to an independent application. I started that application with the following code.

```
private Process app;
app = new Process();
app.StartInfo.FileName = app_path;
app.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = dir_path;
app.Start();
```

Now i want to send Mouse click message to that applicaiton, I have specific coordinates in relative to application window. How can i do it using Windows Messaging or any other technique.

I used

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern void mouse_event(UInt32 dwFlags, UInt32 dx, UInt32 dy, UInt32 dwData, IntPtr dwExtraInfo);
```

It works well but cause the pointer to move as well. So not fit for my need.

Then i use.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = false)]
static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, int lParam);
```

It works well for minimize maximize, but do not work for mouse events.

The codes for mousevents i am using are,

```
WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x201, //Left mousebutton down
WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x202,   //Left mousebutton up
WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK = 0x203, //Left mousebutton doubleclick
WM_RBUTTONDOWN = 0x204, //Right mousebutton down
WM_RBUTTONUP = 0x205,   //Right mousebutton up
WM_RBUTTONDBLCLK = 0x206, //Right mousebutton do
```

Thanks for the help in advance, and waiting for feedback.

Comment: Stop sending input messages, they should be posted. You might be better off using `SendInput()` anyway, that's the right way to fake input.

Answer (score 2):

For a single click you should send two mouse event at the same time for an exact mouse click event.

```
SendMessage(nChildHandle, 0x201, 0, 0); //Mouse left down
SendMessage(nChildHandle, 0x202, 0, 0); //Mouse left up
```

It is working in my project.

Comment: The window doesn't need to be focused to use this does it? Is it possible it be minimized and we can syntehsize clicks with this at certain x and y?

Answer (score 0):

Save the cursor position, use mouse_event and move the cursor back. mouse_event is really the best way to do this.

Comment: A single click involves multiple messages, like mouse move, button down, button up, click, and possibly others. I'm not saying it's impossible to simulate with SendMessage, because it definitely is, it's just a lot harder. You should create a simple forms application which dumps all received messages to a text file and see what happens.

Comment: I just found this library http://www.programmersheaven.com/download/56171/download.aspx , It works very well, but still do not work for the Click. Also tried many other things but click is not working. 

Is there any issue with Windows7, i read some where that Windows Vista + OS have some User interface protection some how. Is it this problem?

Comment: It didn't work on XP either when I tried to poke with an application that didn't want to be poked with.