# Firefox addon click on flash content

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I want to do mouse click simulation on flash content. I found this document from firefox developer site [Simulating mouse and key events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Miscellaneous). I used [this html drawing page](https://awwapp.com/) to test it and it works (see the image below). But when I do same thing on [this drawing page](http://www.slimber.com/painter/) which is flash based, it seems that firefox actually not click on flash content. But anyway it focus the page but I can't see that content has clicked.

This is the code I use for click. (I test this code on `scratchpad`)

```
var utils = window.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIInterfaceRequestor)
                  .getInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIDOMWindowUtils);
utils.sendMouseEvent("mousedown", x, y, 0, 1, 0);
utils.sendMouseEvent("mouseup", x, y, 0, 1, 0);
```

and this is the actual code I used to test it on scatchpad

```
var utils = window.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIInterfaceRequestor)
                  .getInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIDOMWindowUtils);

var x=580;
var y=400;
var counter=0;
var timer;

function simulate(){

  utils.sendMouseEvent("mousedown", x, y, 0, 1, 0);
  utils.sendMouseEvent("mouseup", x, y, 0, 1, 0);
  x++;
  y++;
  if(counter>200){
    clearTimeout(timer);
  }
  counter++;

}

timer=setInterval(function(){simulate();},10);
```

This is what I got when I run it in a html drawing page. But I got nothing when run this script in flash based page.
What I'm asking is how can I do mouse click simulation from firefox addon. But I don't like to use `js-ctypes`. Is it impossible to do mouse simulation on flash content without using native ctypes codes ?

there is some reasons why i don't like `ctypes` .for example it can click on any window not only browser also browser need to be maximized but above method click only on browser and work even when browser is minimized.

[image]

Comment: On Windows you can js-ctypes use SendMessage to send a click into a window even when minimized. But the tab will most likely have to be focused in that minimized window: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5191842/1828637 I dont know about Linux or OSX but would love to learn if possible there too.

Comment: @Noitidart can you provide me a link/document to do it usingjs-ctype ..because ctype give me unexppected behaviours .when i code to click 2 times it clicks 20+ times or zero times.

Comment: Sure man no problem. As don in that stackoverflow topic i linked in my previous comment, you have to use `SendMessage`, this is an example of how to use `SendMessage`: https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/dba9bc4b7572bd3349d1

Comment: ok tnxs i will try that

Comment: Your test above was awesome, please do share your tests you do a great job!